# How to merge a specific dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm wrestling with a big dataframe merge, but here is the problem at a very minimal level...The loop works, but it's so slow...

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4], 
               "B": [ np.nan , 10, np.nan, 20, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,40, np.nan]})

In[1]: df
Out[1]: 
    A     B
0   1   NaN
1   1  10.0
2   2   NaN
3   2  20.0
4   2   NaN
5   3   NaN
6   3   NaN
7   3   NaN
8   3   NaN
9   4  40.0
10  4   NaN
```

## How to obtain df2, without a loop - ?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4], 
               "B": [ 10 , 10, 20, 20, 20, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,40, 40]})

In[1]: df2
Out[18]: 
A     B
0   1  10.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  20.0
3   2  20.0
4   2  20.0
5   3   NaN
6   3   NaN
7   3   NaN
8   3   NaN
9   4  40.0
10  4  40.0
```

Comment: have you tried using a join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [91]: df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
Out[91]:
    A     B
0   1  10.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  20.0
3   2  20.0
4   2  20.0
5   3   NaN
6   3   NaN
7   3   NaN
8   3   NaN
9   4  40.0
10  4  40.0
```

Comment: Thanks! That would be my ideal answer: `df.B = df.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`

Answer (score 0):

If  only have one value per sub group

```
df.B=df.A.map(df.set_index('A').dropna().B.to_dict())
df
Out[717]: 
    A     B
0   1  10.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  20.0
3   2  20.0
4   2  20.0
5   3   NaN
6   3   NaN
7   3   NaN
8   3   NaN
9   4  40.0
10  4  40.0
```